# how to use hasOne and belongsToMany together in cakephp 4?

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-4.x

```php
$this->hasOne('Users');
 
$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
     'through' => 'Memberships'
]);
$this->hasMany('Memberships', [
     'foreignKey' => 'profile_id',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a different alias for one of the associations, they must be unique as they are stored in one and the same collection/registry.

```php
$this->hasOne('PrimaryUsers', [
    'className' => 'Users',
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/associations.html)**